# Adding new programmer to Arduino IDE

Tags: arduino-ide, raspberrypi, programmer

I want to use the Arduino IDE using a raspberry pi with raspbian OS because it's the only way I can read a Digispark usb (I don't have 2.0 usb ports in my laptop so I can't read the usb with it).

I installed arduino IDE 1.8.13 so I can add the Digistump package. The problem I got is that when I try to add the drivers from the link `http://digistump.com/package_digistump_index.json`, it returns `Tool micronucleus is not available for your operating system.`.

I donwloaded micronucleus using

```
git clone https://github.com/micronucleus/micronucleus
```

and installed it. Now I have it but I don't know how the arduino IDE could detect it. Could someone help me on how to make the arduino IDE understand I have it (micronucleus) installed?

Comment: The question could be answered directly, but it's probably easier for you to just insert a USB 2.0 HUB in the path to your device rather than messing around with the Pi and trying to fix the board support to work on the Pi.   Also, my understanding is that micronucleus can work on USB 3.0 *if* you get the correct version installed.

Comment: Which is the _correct version_ ? I’m new in this stuff, so any answer that could help is really useful :-)

Comment: v2.01 (or newer), I think.  Although, the comment seems to suggest it should not have fixed the problems I've seen it fix.  So, dunno.  Sometime in the next week I'll have one of these myself, which is ironic, because I don't recommend them.

Comment: @iam_agf, I found [this](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=461404.0) when looking up "laucher", in the process of doing pretty much exactly what's written there.  I compiled micronucleus under Raspbian, but that's about as far as I went.  Kind of looks like they got it working, so I'm not sure what the point in me continuing with it would be.